# Compiler #if directive to split between Mono and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I need to dual-compile a class library for Mono on the Mac and .NET on the PC. There are some minor changes I want to make, but I was hoping to split the code using a compiler directive. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well you could certainly use

```
#if MONO
```

and then compile with

```
gmcs -define:MONO ...
```

(Or put it in your Mono build configuration, of course. It really depends on how you're building your library.)

... what are you looking for beyond that?

Answer (score 45):

While a runtime check is probably preferable, with the Mono compiler, the pre-defined `__MonoCS__` constant is useful, *e.g.*:

```
#if __MonoCS__
// Code for Mono C# compiler.
#else
// Code for Microsoft C# compiler.
#endif
```

Comment: Just make sure no developer adds __ MonoCS __ to your Visual Studio project build properties and then wonders why the compiled code doesn't work as expected! :-/

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.

Comment: I agree with @BSalita this is the correct answer (and it works). In my particular case, I needed to add an interface to a namespace. The Mono version doesn't have it yet.

Comment: This works exactly opposite for me. I add this `#if __MonoCS__ 
using System.Deployment.Application;
#endif` - and that compiles. Whereas leaving it out fails. The exact opposite of what should logically happen, since I'm compiling in Mono on a Mac.

Answer (score 19):

Preferred way is to use runtime detection, as this allows for the same assemblies to be used on either platform:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main ()
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime");
        if (t != null)
             Console.WriteLine ("You are running with the Mono VM");
        else
             Console.WriteLine ("You are running something else");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not help those of us who'd like to use Mono-specific features...